# Building a relation between a cart and an order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to integrate eCommerce functionality into my rails app, and am having trouble creating a new order.  I start with a cart, which has_many orders, which has_many transactions.  The first field in my order database is cart_id.  I need to be able to access information in the cart (such as total_price) from the view/order/new.html.erb.

Where would be the best place to build this relation, and how?  I can find the cart through the session id, but I don't know how to build the relationship.  I was thinking in the order model, in the new action, somthing like so?

```
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    current_cart.@order.build
```

Defined in my application controller is the function current_cart

```
  def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
  end
```

UPDATE

Here is my new and create function, and where I need the value

```
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @order }
    end
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])

       # THIS IS WHERE I HAVE TRIED TO BUILD THE RELATIONSHIP
       # I have tried current_cart.orders.build, @order.cart = current_cart, and 
       # @order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])

    @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
    if @order.save
      if @order.purchase
        render :action => "success"
      else
        render :action => "failure"
      end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

and this is where I need to access the cart in the model

```
  def price_in_cents
    (cart.total_price*100).round
  end
```

And I always get an exception caught for an undefined function, either the build function, or the total price function

Comment: `current_cart.orders.build`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Order model you have the cart_id, so define the relation there:

```
belongs_to :cart
```

You can also define the relation in the Cart model, additionally:

```
has_many :orders
```

After that you can simply add new orders to your current basket:

```
@order = Order.new
@order.cart = current_cart
```

EDIT:

Maybe there is an other Problem with the current_cart method.

Try:

```
@order.cart_id = session[:cart_id]
```

Comment: Actually, although this works for my purposes, the cart_id is not being saved and is still nill in my database.  Any guesses as to why?

Comment: This must be a different problem. Can you show me the entire new function?

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong but all of the sudden the original solution, @order.cart = current_cart started working again! I must have mistakenly made a typo at some point :D

Answer (score 1):

I made a video about this:  http://www.ror-e.com/info/videos/6

I actually separate the cart from the order.  So basically The cart has_many cart_item and the order has_many order_items.  I'd love to help out more.  Feel free to contact me directly.  I'd love to discuss the pro's & con's of different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

In your create action:

```
@order = current_cart.build_order(order_params)
```

and add strong params:

```
  private

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :card_type, :card_expires_on)
  end
```